How to extract data from an any object or to cast it to a specific type
I having trouble finding how to cast an undefined object to a defined one in Angular TS.
I am having a table that modifies its content with the help of an modal window.
The data from the row populates the fields of the modal window, and after the changes are made, the object sent back is an Pacient type:
constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<pacientModifier>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: PacientModif) {
      this.data={...data};        
    }

  onNoClick(): void {     
    this.dialogRef.close({data:this.data});
  }

but in the dialogRef, the result return is of an undefined type
 dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
          this.updateRowData(result);
        });

The result returned is an undefined object. The object containing the members of the Pacient object.
The pacient object:
export class Pacient {
id = "";
name = " ";
pacient_Condition =" ";
birth_Date=" ";
}

The object return after the modal in returned:
data: Object { id: " ", name: " ", pacient_Condition: " ", birth_Date:"" }

I have tried to cast using result as Pacient or using Object.values(result).
Pacients page template:
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <button md-button (click)="openDialog(element)">Edit</button>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

Open dialog method:
openDialog(row:Pacient): void {
        const dialogRef = this._dialog.open(pacientModifier, {
          width: '250px',
          data: row
        });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
          console.log(result);
          this.updateRowData(result);
        });
      }

Is there a way to acces the data member by member(Id, name, etc) or to convert it directly to a Pacient object?

I assume you meant to use the middle English form for the word Pacient rather than Patient as in someone being treated by a Doctor here

Yes, it was a typo, my mistake.

I have extracted the values from the result object as an array, followed by object destructuring and property shorthand. The members of Pacient object are populated one by one.
extractReponse (response : any,pacient : Pacient){
   pacient.id =(({ id}) => ({id }))(Object.values(response)[0] as Pacient)['id'];
   pacient.name=(({ name}) => ({name }))(Object.values(response)[0] as Pacient)['name'];
   pacient.pacient_Condition=(({ pacient_Condition}) => ({pacient_Condition }))(Object.values(response)[0] as Pacient)['pacient_Condition'];
   pacient.birth_Date=(({ birth_Date}) => ({birth_Date }))(Object.values(response)[0] as Pacient)['birth_Date'];
   console.log('in extraction',pacient);
   return pacient;
}

This post helped me a lot: How to get a subset of a javascript object's properties

try result as unknown as Patient
